# Put text file to a 2D Array (Sudoku Grid)

Tags: java, arrays, 2d, text-files, sudoku

I need to load a .txt file with int like 001 012 017 108 etc.
-> 001 = means column 0, row 0, value 1.
This is the code I have so far, the issue is finding a way to remove the space
which are read as 0 and also print a new line for every rows. Thank you!
Code so far:
The output is: 12345678023456789034567891045678912056789123067891234078912345089123456091234567Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -49

```
public static void main (String [] args) {
    int[][] sudokuGrid = new int [9][9];

    try {
        FileReader fichierALire = new FileReader("partie1.txt");
        int c = fichierALire.read();
        while (c != -1){
            int row = fichierALire.read();
            int value = fichierALire.read();
            fichierALire.read();
            sudokuGrid [c-48][row-48] = value-48;
            c = fichierALire.read();
            System.out.print(sudokuGrid[c-48][row-48]);
        }

    } catch (IOException exception) {
        System.out.println("Il y a une erreur lors de la lecture: " + exception.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Read the data line by line (instead of character by character).

> the issue is finding a way to remove the space

Then as you read each line you can use the `String.split(..)` method.

It will then return you an Array of your values. Then you can iterate through each entry in the array and parse the value and populate your grid.